# spring autowire collection, order default bean last

Tags: java, spring

I am autowiring a collection of strategies using spring. Each strategy is evaluated first using `isApplicable()` method and if `true`, that strategy is selected. 
I have a default strategy whose `isApplicable()` method always returns `true`. I want this default strategy bean to be autowired LAST in the strategies collection.

I see one option of doing that using the `@Order` annotation. But the problem is this way, I will force anyone who implements a new strategy to specify and Order on their bean. I want to avoid that. Only want the default bean to be last in collection.

Do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: What did you end up doing for this?

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring 4, @Order is the correct way to achieve what you want.  Since you do not want to enforce @Order on any implementations of the Strategy interface, here is an approach that will work for you, and ensure the default strategy is chosen last.

1. Counter-intuitively, annotate the default Strategy with  @Order(value=Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
2. Do not annotate any other implementations with @Order.
3. Prior to selecting the strategy from the collection, remove the top strategy from the list (which is guaranteed to be the default strategy) and place it at the bottom of the collection.  There is code below which demonstrates this.
4. Iterate through the strategies and choose the first applicable one.

As a test, I created StrategyA, StrategyB, and DefaultStrategy.  If I mark StrategyA or StrategyB as applicable, they are always chosen first.  Only if both are not applicable, only then does the DefaultStrategy get chosen (see output at the end to see this test case).

Here is a sample Strategy, with no @Order annotation, which will be either applicable, or not.  I tested both applicable=true, and false, and got the expected result.

```
@Component
public class StrategyA implements Strategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "STRATEGY A";
    }

}
```

Here is the default Strategy, which is always applicable, which is to be choosen LAST.

```
@Component
@Order(value=Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DefaultStrategy implements Strategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable() {
        return true;    // Always true
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Default; should be chosen last";
    }

}
```

Here is the logic to ensure that the default strategy is choosen LAST.

```
@Component
public class StrategyChooser {

    @Autowired
    private List<Strategy> strategies;

    public Strategy getStrategy() {

        Strategy defaultStrategy = strategies.remove(0);  // Remove the default strategy from the top of the list
        strategies.add(strategies.size(), defaultStrategy); // And make it last

        for (Strategy strategy : getStrategies()) {
            System.out.println("Considering strategy="+strategy.getName());
            if (strategy.isApplicable())
                return strategy;
        }
        return strategies.get(strategies.size()-1);     // Return the last in case the default is not defined 
    }
}
```

Output when all other strategies are 'not applicable' (demonstrates that Default will come last):

```
Considering strategy=STRATEGY A
Considering strategy=STRATEGY B
Considering strategy=Default; should be chosen last
```

Comment: Cave at:  as of now.  it should be LOWEST_PRECEDENCE. to be last one